# Customizing Django's server configurations

Tags: python, django, http

On firing up python's development server: `>$ python manage.py runserver`, by default it provides a default IP address and such, with the output:

```
>$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...
0 errors found
February 12, 2014 - 23:20:35
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'counter.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

How do I provide my own settings for an HTTP server? I want to specify my own port, ip address, as well as my own request handler. I added the following code in my `models.py` file, but it doesn't seem to be running. No print statements are being shown. My code is below:

```
def run():
    print "starting run"
    port = 8080
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', port)
    httpd = HTTPServer (server_address, Counter_HTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.server_forever()
    assert False # unreachab;e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Am I supposed to provide this code somewhere else? I understand I can specify my own IP and PORT as arguments to `runserver`, but how I do execute my `main - run()` method so that I can specify my custom http request handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runverver takes port as an argument, run it as manage.py runserver 8080 to run on 8080

For more complex requirements, you might want to try something like uwsgi.

None of your print statements added in models.py work because when you runserver, you don't run models.py, you just import models from it.